# React Native Unable to import SDK into AppDelegate.m - Getting "Use of undeclared identifier"

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native

github repo: https://github.com/namninja/iterableone
SDK Docs: https://support.iterable.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045714132-Installing-Iterable-s-React-Native-SDK-

I am having issues installing an SDK into my RN Test App. I can get the App to run, but when I begin the steps to implement Push Notifications and need to import the SDK into my iOS AppDelegate.mm file, it is not recognizing the SDK.

At the top of my AppDelegate.mm I am adding `@import IterableSDK;` then within AppDelegate adding

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
[IterableAPI registerToken:deviceToken];
}
```

However, I am getting the error *Use of undeclared identifier 'IterableAPI'*
[image]
PODS are installed and updated, I also tried adding in a dummy .swift file created with bridging headers, but no matter what I do, I can't reference the SDK.

I'm assuming other Developers are able to work with the SDK just fine and there is nothing on the support site describing my issue.  Not sure how to proceed and any advice, time and help is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. So the Issue is that there is a conflict with the latest version of React Native and the Iterable SDK. I downgraded to RN 0.64.0 and was able to get it working as expected.